# State возвращает предыдущее значение вместо актуального

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть вопрос.

Задача - написать небольшой виджет на React, который берет из массива инфу о городах (формируется выпадающий список) и затем передает ее в виде строки к fetch-запросу.

Вот сам код в песочнице:

https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-66iz3n?file=/src/index.js

Проблема заключается в том, что значение value, которое передается в функцию setUserZone - это название предыдущего города/региона, которое было выбрано пользователем.

При этом я вывожу value отдельно в html - проблем нет, отображается корректно. Я явно пропустил где-то колбек, но где? Помогите, плз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, т.к. запись в стейт и рендер - это асинхронные операции.

Что бы исправить, достаточно вашу функцию вынести в useEffect

```
  const handleZoneChange = (event) => {
    setValue(() => event.target.value);
    //setUserZone(() => value);
  };

  const getTime = (value) => {
    fetch(`https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/${value}`) // fetching     data from server
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTime(data)) // saving data to time variable with setTime
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   getTime(value);
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
   getTime('Asia/Yekaterinburg');
  }, []);
```

Как только значение value поменяется, будет вызван хук useEffect(), который получит как раз обновленное значение стейта. хук будет срабатывать только при изменении значения переменной value(список зависимостей хука)

Comment: Реально так, без useEffect не обойтись. Спасибо, добрый человек!

Comment: Скажи, а как добавить обновление каждые пять секунд для обновленного поиска?

В useEffect, который я инициализирую при первой загрузке, это просто - внутрь помещаю setInterval и всё.

Но с новым useEffect, который срабатывает при выборе региона, такое уже не работает.

Comment: @АнтонБлаговещенский Тогда можно из данного хук вызвать функцию и передавать ей на вход в качестве параметра обновленное значение

Comment: Хм, внезапно сработал setInterval внутри useEffect.

Comment: @АнтонБлаговещенский Я немного обновил ответ. Не обратил внимание, что у вас есть еще дублирование кода. В функцию запихайте `setInterval` и не забудте при каждом вызове сначала остановить предыдущий `clearInterval()`

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже модернизировал ваш ответ, чтобы все работало.

Comment: Вопрос был - почему старое значение - ответил почему и показал как исправить. А уже детали реализации вашего приложения и методов компонентов уже сами придумывайте )

Comment: @АнтонБлаговещенский Если вы ответ принимаете и он помог вам решить ваш вопрос, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа "Принять ответ"

Comment: Меня смущает ещё одна вещь. Я добавил setInterval внутрь useEffect, чтобы время автоматически обновлялось с сервера каждые пять секунд.

Однако при выборе нового региона из списка также приходится ждать по пять секунд, пока не закончится время для setInterval. Почему не срабатывает useEffect?

https://mmoresun.github.io/live-clock/

Готовый проект лежит тут, там же есть ссылка на сорцы.

Comment: Наверное потому, что вместо возврата результата запускается timeout(интервал). Либо дергай сервер и пускай интервал, либо... надо код смотреть детально. Не разберешься, оформи новый пост уже с указанием конкретной проблемы и желаемого результата

Comment: Так и сделал.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1459029/%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-deps-useeffect-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-setinterval-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5